# Date Format Options in Oracle External Table

Tags: sql, oracle, external-tables

I have created an external table, everything looks good except for one of the date format, it looks like it defaults to MM/DD/YYYY but I want it as YYYYMMDD as it is in the file. The column is DATE_ID. Anyone have any clues?

Thanks!

```
CREATE TABLE R2SCHD.AAFES_RDF_XTRNL_CAL_HIER
(
  DATE_ID           DATE,
  DATE_DESC         DATE,
  WEEK_ID           VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  WEEK_DESC         DATE,
  MNTH_ID           VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  MNTH_DESC         VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  QRTR_ID           VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  QRTR_DESC         VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  HALF_ID           VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  HALF_DESC         VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  YEAR_ID           VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  YEAR_DESC         VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  DOW_ID            VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  DOW_DESC          VARCHAR2(25 BYTE)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY R2SCHD_STATIC_DATA
     ACCESS PARAMETERS 
     ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
       NOBADFILE
       NOLOGFILE
       NODISCARDFILE
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
       MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
      (
       DATE_ID CHAR(8) DATE_FORMAT DATE MASK "YYYYMMDD",
       DATE_DESC CHAR(10) DATE_FORMAT DATE MASK "MM/DD/YYYY",
       WEEK_ID,
       WEEK_DESC CHAR(10) DATE_FORMAT DATE MASK "MM/DD/YYYY",
       MNTH_ID, MNTH_DESC, QRTR_ID, QRTR_DESC, HALF_ID, 
       HALF_DESC, YEAR_ID, YEAR_DESC, DOW_ID, DOW_DESC
      )
     )
    LOCATION (R2SCHD_STATIC_DATA:'rdft_cal_external.dat')
  )
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED
NOPARALLEL
NOMONITORING;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You created the date_id as DATE data type, which is **correct**. Dates do not have a "format" - what you see on your screen, with slashes, is dictated by your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting. What are you using - SQL*Plus? SQL Developer? Toad?

For example in SQL Developer: Tools - Preferences - Database - NLS and you will see (and be able to change) your date format. That is what controls what is shown on your screen - not the format you used for your external table (it won't help you to set it as 'YYYYMMDD' there).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am using Toad, but is there any way I can just use the NLS_DATE_FORMAT for only one particular column? As I do not want to change the settings to output for all columns. If so, would this only change it for my session. How do I do so for all future sessions from all users? Sorry for the bombardment of questions.

Comment: Dates that are stored, correctly, in the date data type in the database are always converted to string for display on your screen. (While they remain dates in the database, that is not affected!) If you do not provide an explicit to_char() command, Oracle does it for you. It is almost always best, for showing on screen, to use to_char with an explicit date format, for example to_char(date_id, 'YYYYMMDD'). Then you don't need the NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter. But then your SELECT can't just be SELECT * FROM... (which is bad practice anyway).